# keep content centered while stretching backgrounds

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want my website to have this horizontally split background look while keeping the content in a container of 980px, like this site http://votezachandleah.com/

I have done this by setting a height and background color to the divs but when i put them in the container it cuts the background color down to 980px...

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}

#another_section {
    background-color: #66cc33;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
}

#background {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333
    height:600px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="background">
     </div>
    <div id="another_section">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because the background-color is for the divs inside container, so the color can't fill an area larger than the container, when it is given an explicit width of 980px. What do you want, specifically?

Comment: Try putting container inside background instead of the other way around.

Comment: What I am looking for is the divs that have a height of 600px and 650px stretch horizontally indefinitely when you zoom out. I am trying  something with breaking up the background behind the divs so it looks like the divs continue their color horizontally. I feel like there should be an easier fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the body the same colors as the container.